# Why does Hibernate not allow Strings to be dynamically entered as primary keys for a table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three entities, say A, B and C. A contains multiple instances of B and C. B and C have String fields as their primary key which are meant to be populated at runtime. The codes are as follows:

Class A:

```
@Entity
public class A
{
 private int id;
 private B[] bSet = null;
 private C[] cSet = null;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 public int getId()
 {return id;}

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
 @OrderColumn(name = "bIndex")
 public B[] getBset()
 {return bSet;}

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
 @OrderColumn(name = "cIndex")
 public C[] getCset()
 {return cSet;}
}
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
public class B
{
 private String bId;
 private A a;

 @Id
 public String getBId()
 {return bId;}

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 public A getA(A a)
 {return a;}
}
```

Class C:

```
@Entity
public class C
{
 private String cId;
 private A a;

 @Id
 public String getCId()
 {return cId;}

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 public A getA(A a)
 {return a;}
}
```

If I try to persist a B entity in my application, Hibernate does not go for an insert, as I saw after enabling Hibernate logging. It is trying for an update, and throwing this exception.

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

This problem hasn't been answered satisfactorily anywhere. I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625059/org-hibernate-stalestateexception-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-fr), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124361/hibernate-delete-error-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count) and [here](http://java-fp.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/orghibernatestalestateexception-batch.html). As they say, Hibernate expects a primary id of null while saving, and if it's anything else, it goes for updating the row, and throws this exception. But I need to insert rows with these Strings as primary keys. So what can I do for that? Please help me with this.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I think I'm fighting a losing battle here. It seems that this is a bug in Hibernate itself, and until Hibernate devs solve it, we can't do this. Just look [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HIBERNATE-125).

Comment: Can you try to save B and C individually and see? String primary key is not the problem here. Looks like something do do with mapping or locking mode

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep a reference of A for every B and C saved. In fact, this is the subject matter of another question which I posted just an hour back or so. So I can't save B or C individually. They all have to work together.

Comment: Can you try replacing B[] with list<B>. Hibernate supports set, list, map, bag only. May be that could be an issue..

Comment: @Zeus, Simple arrays work fine. The problem definitely isn't there. When I replace the String primary key with a dummy auto-generated int one, all the rows of B are being persisted without any problem.

Comment: @abhishek, Post the code how you are trying to persist the entites and also the complete stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: @Chaitanya, I did that last night in my other question. Did you go through it?

Comment: Given that your id specifies a generator, Hibernate could probably assume that when id==null => insert, when id!= null => update.

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen, the problem is for the primary keys of B and C, which have String primary keys and cannot be auto-generated. I haven't mentioned the problem for class A at all. If you look at the codes for either class B or C, you will find that none of them have generators specified.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it fully, nor test it locally, just providing tips. Should't it access A when persisting B? Have you added debug info from org.hibernate.event.internal (show flushing events), and org.hibernate.internal.util (pretty print managed entities). That helps me occasionally

Comment: @abhishek For class B and C, you did not mention generator strategy. Use "assigned" and set the primary key for B and C before persisting. Please let me know if this works