# Spring boot deleting an entity in unit test causes StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dbunit

I am using Spring Boot (2.1.4) and attempt to write a simple unit test to delete
an entity. The entity (some parts omitted for brevity):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Getter
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "attribute_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected UUID attributeId;

    @Version
    protected Date version;

    @Getter
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String value;

}
```

The entity has a simple repository:

```java
public interface MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    Optional<MyEntity> findByMyId(UUID id);

}
```

The unit tests uses an in memory database:

```java
spring:
  jpa:
    database: H2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
    generate-ddl: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

The tests itself (using [database-rider](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider)):

```java
@Test
@DataSet(value = INITIAL, transactional = true)
void delete() {
    Optional<MyEntity> v = repository.findByMyId(SECOND.getAttributeId());
    assertThat(v.isPresent()).isTrue();
    repository.delete(v.get());
    v = repository.findByMyId(SECOND.getAttributeId());
}
```

The last line in the test throws the following exception:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3480)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3737)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
```

all the other tests for save and find are working as expected, only using delete
is causing this.

I've tried several suggested solutions from other posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625059/org-hibernate-stalestateexception-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-fr/22489680) is a similar post but it didn't solve my problem)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [@ExpectedDataSet](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider/#expected-dataset)? in this way you let dbrider assert the state of the database after test execution:

```
@Test
@DataSet(value = INITIAL, transactional = true)
@ExpectedDataSet("expected.yml")
void delete() {
    Optional<MyEntity> v = repository.findByMyId(SECOND.getAttributeId());
    assertThat(v.isPresent()).isTrue();
    repository.delete(v.get());
    //v = repository.findByMyId(SECOND.getAttributeId()); let dbrider assert that for you
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access  `v = repository.findByMyId(SECOND.getAttributeId());` after performing deletion which is not committed yet.

Comment: How do I commit it prior to the assertion in the test? Didn't encounter this kind of behavior before in deletions, not sure what is different.